# I cannot display the values of the 2 table Ceremony and Referee

Tags: oracle

```
create table STADIUM
( stad_location varchar2(20) primary key
, stad_name varchar2(10)
, stad_capacity number(5)
, match_ID char(8)
, stall_ID char(4)
, foreign key (match_ID) references MATCH (match_ID) ON DELETE SET NULL
, foreign key (stall_ID) references STALL (stall_ID) ON DELETE SET NULL); 

create table TRANSPORTATION 
(registra_no char(6) primary key
, transp_type varchar2(10)
, capacity number(2)
); 

create table CEREMONY 
(cerem_type varchar2(10) primary key
, cerem_name varchar2(15)
, FIFA_theme_song varchar2(20)
, p_ID char(8)
, stad_location varchar2(20)
, foreign key (p_ID) references PERFORMER(p_ID) ON DELETE SET NULL
, foreign key (stad_location) references STADIUM(stad_location)ON DELETE SET NULL
); 

create table REFEREE( ref_ID char(8) primary key
, ref_name varchar2(20)
, yo_exp number(2)
, match_ID char(8)
, registra_no char(6)
, foreign key (match_ID) references MATCH (match_ID) ON DELETE SET NULL
, foreign Key (registra_no) references TRANSPORTATION(registra_no) ON DELETE SET NULL); 

insert into CEREMONY values('Opening', 'Speech', 'Colors', 'PP561475', 'Al-Waab Street'); 

insert into REFEREE values('RF503624','Mike Dean', 25, 'MM129456', 'QLM729'); select * from CEREMONY; 

select * from REFEREE;
```

Answer (score 0):

Bunch of tables are missing, referenced by foreign keys so I'm creating them first:

```
SQL> -- Missing tables, referenced by foreign keys
SQL> create table match (match_id char(8) primary key);

Table created.

SQL> create table stall (stall_id char(4) primary key);

Table created.

SQL> create table performer (p_id char(8) primary key);

Table created.

SQL>
```

Your tables:

```
SQL> create table STADIUM
  2  ( stad_location varchar2(20) primary key
  3  , stad_name varchar2(10)
  4  , stad_capacity number(5)
  5  , match_ID char(8)
  6  , stall_ID char(4)
  7  , foreign key (match_ID) references MATCH (match_ID) ON DELETE SET NULL
  8  , foreign key (stall_ID) references STALL (stall_ID) ON DELETE SET NULL);

Table created.

SQL> create table TRANSPORTATION
  2  (registra_no char(6) primary key
  3  , transp_type varchar2(10)
  4  , capacity number(2)
  5  );

Table created.

SQL> create table CEREMONY
  2  (cerem_type varchar2(10) primary key
  3  , cerem_name varchar2(15)
  4  , FIFA_theme_song varchar2(20)
  5  , p_ID char(8)
  6  , stad_location varchar2(20)
  7  , foreign key (p_ID) references PERFORMER(p_ID) ON DELETE SET NULL
  8  , foreign key (stad_location) references STADIUM(stad_location)ON DELETE SET NULL
  9  );

Table created.

SQL> create table REFEREE( ref_ID char(8) primary key
  2  , ref_name varchar2(20)
  3  , yo_exp number(2)
  4  , match_ID char(8)
  5  , registra_no char(6)
  6  , foreign key (match_ID) references MATCH (match_ID) ON DELETE SET NULL
  7  , foreign Key (registra_no) references TRANSPORTATION(registra_no) ON DELETE SET NULL);

Table created.

SQL>
```

Inserts into tables referenced by `ceremony` and `referee`:

```
SQL> insert into performer values ('PP561475');

1 row created.

SQL> insert into stadium (stad_location) values ('Al-Waab Street');

1 row created.

SQL> insert into match values ('MM129456');

1 row created.

SQL> insert into transportation (registra_no) values ('QLM729');

1 row created.

SQL>
```

Your inserts & result of your `select` statements:

```
SQL> insert into CEREMONY values('Opening', 'Speech', 'Colors', 'PP561475', 'Al-Waab Street');

1 row created.

SQL> insert into REFEREE values('RF503624','Mike Dean', 25, 'MM129456', 'QLM729');

1 row created.

SQL> select * from CEREMONY;

CEREM_TYPE CEREM_NAME      FIFA_THEME_SONG      P_ID     STAD_LOCATION
---------- --------------- -------------------- -------- --------------------
Opening    Speech          Colors               PP561475 Al-Waab Street

SQL> select * from REFEREE;

REF_ID   REF_NAME                 YO_EXP MATCH_ID REGIST
-------- -------------------- ---------- -------- ------
RF503624 Mike Dean                    25 MM129456 QLM729

SQL>
```

Therefore, if you do everything right, everything *is* right.